# Cómo validar un campo unico con jQuery Validation en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validación, jquery-validate

He seguido este tutorial para validar un formulario en rails con el plugin jquery validation: https://sleekd.com/tutorials/jquery-validation-in-ruby-on-rails/

las validaciones me funcionan correctamente excepto cuando tengo que validar un campo unico, en el tutorial explican como validar un email, pero ya he intentado de todo, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor gracias

Esto es algo del ejemplo:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#new_user").validate({
       debug: true,
         rules: {
         "user[email]": {required: true, email: true, remote:"/users/check_email" },
         "user[password]": {required: true, minlength: 6},
         "user[password_confirmation]": {required: true, equalTo:  "#user_password"}
        }
    });
});    

def check_email
 @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => !@user }
  end
 end
```

en routes.rb:

```
map.check_email "users/check_email", :controller => "users", :action => "check_email"
map.resources :users
```

Comment: porque no utilizas las validaciones de rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 1):

En el código que muestras estas realizando una validación de front end, el problema esta en que en esta instancia no tienes acceso a informacion del servidor como por ejemplo para identificar si no existe un campo repetido, para ello podrias usar una validación a nivel de servidor, Active Record de Rails te permite realizar fácilmente este tipo de validaciones.

Ejemplo

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

Te recomiendo revisar:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html